# How to associate an Eclipse perspective to a file type?

Tags: eclipse

How to associate an Eclipse perspective to a file type independent from the Eclipse project?

For example, if I open a `*.frm` file I want the following view.:

[image: form editor / properties view]

If I open a `*.js` file I want to have this:

[image: js editor / outline view]

Is that possible?

How is the Debug perspective initiated? Is the Debug perspective project independent, because in a lot of project types there is a Debug perspective?

Comment: Do you want to implement this in your own project?

Comment: @GGrec It is not general project related, but in this case it's a [Servoy project](https://www.servoy.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=19759). If it's not possible to have this as user, I'm interested in how to implement such a feature.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for an implementation, you could check the extension of the file you've just opened, then change perspectives programmatically:

```
try 
{
     PlatformUI.getWorkbench().showPerspective("perspective.id", PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow());
} 
catch (WorkbenchException e) 
{
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Edit:**

Oh, and for the Eclipse project settings, go to **Preferences -> General -> Perspectives**.

Comment: So it's not possible to open a perspective related to a file extension without implementing it yourself? Just for clarification, my question is not related to a project. This is related to all Eclipse projects.

Comment: AFAIK from my research. You could wait for more answers.

Answer (score -1):

1.Click on “Window” in the top-menu.
2.Expand the section “General”  under preferences.
3.Then, expand the section “Editors”.
4.        Now, click on “File Associations”.
5.        You should see “File Type” and “Associated Editors” in right panel.
6.        In “File Type” – you can add (click on a button with name Add should be seen next to this panel) any file-type or file extension
7.    you want make sure you add it with wild-card entry (ex: *.tpl).
8.        Select the above newly added file-type and you should see no editors for this under “Associated Editors” panel – because this is
    newly added.
9.        Now click on Add button next to “Associated Editors” panel to add the editors, it should show the list of available editors,
    choose the one you like.
10.        Click OK and choose this as your default editor by clicking a button “Default” appears next to this panel.

Comment: I don't want to add an editor to a filetype. I want to add a complete perspective to a filetype. For example If I open `*.frm` file this file already opens in the form-editor, but additionally I want to see at the right side the propertier-editor. If I before edit a `*.js` file in the javascript-editor and I have on the right side the outline view and then I switch to the form-editor I want to open automatically on the right side the properties-editor.